# Rigging a single model that has multiple outfits, accessories and hairs

Tags: modeling, rigging, rigify

I have a custom model that I can quickly add a rigify rig to it without trouble. This model, however, has many different outfits, optional accessories, and even different hairstyles that I can simply toggle on or off if I want to.

But when processing this model with all the outfits and everything else, some layers are chock-full of controllers. One single layer has all the hair bones, making it nearly impossible to know which controls what part of the hair. Same with the accessories.

What is the best way to still have the option of all of those outfits, hairs and accessories, but not overwhelm the rig layers? Should I make different saves of this one model with one set of clothing + hair (totalling about 8 saves), or is there a way to toggle both a hair/outfit/accessory and its controllers somehow? What if I want to mix and match different parts of the outfits and their accessories, so Hair from outfit X while wearing outfit Y?

Any help is appreciated!